# Does memoization work on smple .select with strings?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

So basically I am selecting a slice of my state using strings and am wondering if I still benefit from memoization, since the call should be pure.

```
this.store.select('state', 'loginFeature', 'loggedPerson').subscribe(loggedPerson => this.loggedPerson = loggedPerson);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, memoization only happens within `createSelectors`.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/selector.ts#L82